# Android ArrayAdapter with Object and Get some data from that object

Tags: android, object, android-arrayadapter

Im trying to make ListView using data from Array, but I need to get Id of clicked row (not shown in that row, but userd in creation of that product)

Im using this class for object:

```
package com.example.raidplanner;
public class RaidWpis {
private int id;
private int id_gildia;
private String nazwa;
private int schemat;
private int data_zapis;
private int data_start;
private int opis;
private int id_officer;
private int nick_officer;
private int typ;

public RaidWpis(int id,String nazwa) {
    setNazwa(nazwa);
    setId(id);
}

public int getId()                  { return id; }

public void setId(int id)           { this.id = id; }

public String getNazwa()            { return nazwa; }

public void setNazwa(String nazwa)  { this.nazwa = nazwa; }

public String toString() {
        return this.nazwa;
    }
    public String toString2() {
        return this.id+" - "+nazwa;
    }

}
```

And this code in Activity:

```
RaidWpis[] items = {
            new RaidWpis(1, "aaaa"),
            new RaidWpis(3, "bbbb"),
            new RaidWpis(6, "cccc"),
            new RaidWpis(11, "dddd"),
            new RaidWpis(17, "eeee"),
        };        
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  

    ArrayAdapter<RaidWpis> raidList = new ArrayAdapter<RaidWpis>(this, R.layout.simplerow, items);  

    // Create ArrayAdapter using the raid list.  
    mainListView.setAdapter(raidList);

    mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) 
          {
                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get Id of clicked row (not shown in that row, but userd in creation of that product)

Try this in your `onItemClick()` method:

```
RaidWpis obj = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position); // or just raidList.get(position) if raidList is a field variable
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), obj.getID() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: when I use it i get error in Eclipse: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method get(int) is undefined for the type capture#1-of ?
 - Line breakpoint:Raidy_lista [line: 60] - onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, 
  int, long)

Comment: Sorry, it should be `getItem()` not `get()`. I don't believe you need to cast the Adapter with `(ArrayAdapter<RaidWpis> parent.getAdapter()).getItem(position)`, but I'm away from my compiler at the moment.

Comment: Thanks a Lot, I Added Cast to RaidWpis and your solution worked just fine.

Comment: Glad I could help, please click the check mark in this answer to accept it as the solution.

Comment: Sry but I dont have 15 rep to do this.

Answer (score 1):

from the position, you can get the RaidWpis Object by using raidList.get(position). Once you have this RaidWpis object, you can call getId() to get the id